# How to solve exponents using log?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

How can I solve an exponent in a equation using base 10 logarithm tables?
For an example,
$$a = b^x$$
can be written as $$ \log_{10} a= x\log_{10}b $$
                  $$  x = \frac{ \log_{10}b }{\log_{10}a} $$
After this point I can refer values for $\log a$ and $\log b$ from the table. From this point how can I solve to get $x$. Can I subtract values since log division is subtraction??? Or should I take antilog. I'm Kinda stuck here Can Anyone help?

Comment: If you have the values for $\log a$ and $\log b$, you just need to divide the value for $x$ ...

Comment: If you have value table use it in this stage, you have $\log a/\log b$ and not $\log(a/b)$ so you can't use antilog nor make it subtraction

Comment: Be careful, log division is $\log(a/b)$ and that can be rewritten as subtraction.  However, division of logs is $\log(a)/\log(b)$ and is not subtraction.

Comment: The identity that is applicable is $\frac{\log_{10}b}{\log_{10}a}=\log_ab$. However, depending on the table you have, you are probably better off  keeping it this way, or even splitting the logs further as $\log_{10}b=\frac{\ln b}{\ln 10}$ and $\log_{10}a=\frac{\ln a}{\ln 10}$, if the table is of natural logarithms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you're pretty much done. For example, let's say you've found $\log_{10}b = 6$ and $\log_{10}a = 2$. Then $x = \frac{6}{2} = 3$.

Comment: thnxx.. But What if I get bar values How to divide then??

Comment: @sahaisu I'm not sure what you mean. Can you give me an example of a bar value?

Comment: If we assume the same values for a and b  log a*10^-3 = 3bar.2

Comment: @sahaisu My example works if $a=10^2$. Then $a \cdot 10^{-3} = 10^{-1}$, so $\log_{10}(a\cdot 10^{-3}) = -1$. What does "3bar.2" mean?

Comment: Ahh yeah. But If we take a value for a such as 0.02  then referring log tables value for two is 0.3010 And for 0.02  is $$ \bar 2.3010 $$ So when solving using bar values such as above How can I divide?

Comment: @sahaisu I think that just means $-2 + 0.3010$. If $\log_{10}2 = 0.3010$, then $\log_{10}0.02 = \log_{10}(2 \cdot 10^{-2}) = \log_{10}2 + \log_{10}10^{-2} = 0.3010 + (-2) = -2 + 0.3010$

Comment: yhh.. Thanx that Solves it.